# Responsive Side Menu with PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'd like to create a responsive menu with PrimeFaces. While I found several menu options, my menu does not become responsive. Is there an additional styleClass or attribute which I could use?

I do not find anything in documentation so far... May it be only included in commercial premium themes? Since I am not an expert in css, if so, would it be easy to add it to community themes?

Although I think it might be straight forward, just for clarification what I consider as responsive here: The menu should be able to slide away if the user wants it to or resizes the browser or uses another devices (like a smartphone). Basically the same behavior as the menu displayed at the left side in Primefaces ShowCase reveals (I also added two screenshots below).

[PrimeFaces Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUumu.png)

[PrimeFaces Menu Smaller Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8irid.png)